# Recursion in Haskell - Sum of number read from keyboard

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying sum numbers read from the keyboard but i don't get it, in the function sumNums for example i put 7 and i can input 8 numbers but just add 7, i want that input 7 and add 7. In the main function i don't get to use sumNums

```
getInt :: IO Int 
getInt = do
 s <- getLine
 return (read s)

sumNums :: Integer -> IO Int
sumNums n = do
  x<-getInt
  if n==0 
    then return 0
    else do
         rest <- sumNums (n-1)
         return (x+rest)

main = do putStrLn "Type numbers: "
 suma <- sumNums 7
 putStrLn "Sum: " ++ show sum
 average <- suma/7
 putStrLn "Average: " ++ show average
```

Comment: Try terminating with `n == 1`; also, you cannot apply `(/)` to `Integral` types. Try casting `suma` with `fromIntegral`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you read a number, *then* you check if the value of `n` indicates you should be reading another number. Instead, check the value of `n` first.

```
sumNums 0 = return 0
sumNums n = do
  rest <- sumNums (n - 1)
  x <- getInt
  return (x + rest)
```

However, you should try to avoid explicit recursion when you can. Many common patterns have already been abstracted away behind higher-order functions.

Here, what do you want? You want to sum a list of numbers, which you can get by running `getInt` some number of times. Start with the `replicate` function to repeat `getInt` the desired number of times:

```
> :t replicate 3 getInt
replicate 3 getInt :: [IO Int]
```

Then use `sequence` to extract all the integers into a single list.

```
> :t sequence (replicate 3 getInt)
sequence (replicate 3 getInt) :: IO [Int]
```

Finally, you can lift `sum` into the `IO` monad to add up the numbers.

```
> :t sum <$> sequence (replicate 3 getInt)
sum <$> sequence (replicate 3 getInt) :: IO Int
```

Thus, you can write `sumNums` simply as

```
sumNums n = sum <$> sequence (replicate n getInt)
```

---

More simply, `replicateM` combines `sequence` with `replicate` (effectively, `replicateM = (sequence . ) . replicate`).

```
import Control.Monad
sumNums n = sum <$> replicateM n getInt
```

Comment: I'd probably go one step further: `sumNums n = sum <$> replicateM n getInt`

Comment: @user2297560 Indeed, I forgot about `replicateM`.